# Создать поиск по таблице html

Tags: html, ajax

Как сделать поиск по html таблице с помощью ajax,ч чтобы был поиск по всем полям

Comment: с помощью javascript(jquery) может а не ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Вот хороший плагин для поиска по таблице.
https://deuxhuithuit.github.io/quicksearch/

Сами пишите, по каким колонкам искать. 
Если искать по всем то вызов функции будет таким:

```
($('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr'));
```

Comment: в вопросе же ясно написано - "с помощью ajax". Где ajax? :)

Comment: По моим соображениям, так было бы легче намного